# Order by Date in MySQL where date is %D

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've been racking my brains over this one, I can't work it out.
I'm trying a new way to show a date on my site (%D %W) for easier reading, but in the process it's knocked all my "ORDER by" out of sync, so instead of:

8th Friday
9th Saturday
10th Sunday
11th Monday

I'm getting

10th
11th
8th
9th

Now I understand why it's displaying it like it is, but I just don't know the correct way to implement the ORDER by statement, this is what I had before:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%D %W') AS `Date` 
FROM employees WHERE type = 'blah' 
ORDER BY `Date` ASC, `time` ASC
```

Any ideas? Probably an easy one for some.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the original date for sorting and use the "friendly date" for display, like this:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%D %W') AS FormattedDate FROM employees WHERE type = 'blah' ORDER BY Date ASC, time ASC
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thankyou very much and thanks for such a quick response :)